# Can I using difference admob Interstitial in difference mobile app version

Tags: android, ionic-framework, admob

I have an application named **ABCDEF** version 1.0, version 2.0 and so on. Now I want to using difference admob Interstitial ID for each my app version.
ex: Version 1.0 use Interstitial ID 12312312/12312
Version 2.0 use Interstitial ID 12312312/342342
....
Can I do it?

Regards,
Bill

Comment: Answer is yes - you can create separate Interstitial ID's within the same admob app and link release specific ID's. But don't create new Admob App, you can link your app in Admob only once.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I will do it for my app  ^__^